# CICD cannot release database due to 'Deny Public Access'

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am new to CICD process and Azure DevOps.

I am trying to perform a release for my database from one environment to the other using the Azure DevOps release pipeline.

I am unable to successfully perform the release due to the following error message:

```
An instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
Connection was denied since Deny Public Network Access is set to Yes. 
To connect to this server, use the Private Endpoint from inside your virtual network (https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/sql-database/sql-database-private-endpoint-overview#how-to-set-up-private-link-for-azure-sql-database).
```

I am using Service Principal as the authentication method, where I have created the required Service Connection in Azure DevOps.

Note: I am also connected to a VPN when performing the operations.

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that if you need MS Hosted agent you need enable public access on Sql Server level (you will find it in `Firewalls and virtual networks` tab):

[image]

Comment: @sqlenthusiast can you consider upvoting my answer if it was helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

These are the possible ways out:

1. Redeploy your Azure resource and choose Deny Public Network Access to “No” before deploying the resources. Where if you want to make an end-to-end connection with Azure DB the "Deny Public access" should be in “NO”.
2. Establish a private endpoint to connect- If you want to make a secure connection/ Private connection you need to enable Ptivate end point / service end point connection between your two resources (Azure DB and Devops app)

Else  you can  setup private link if they don't want to redeploy to change the settings: : [Quickstart - Create a Private Endpoint using the Azure portal | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/create-private-endpoint-portal)